# sql code error when put in the c# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

A friend of mine has a problem, she has done a project in c# and everything looks fine, but the problem is that, she gets error with the SQL query when she puts it in the code, but when we try the code in microsoft SQL Server it works.

Here is thee example f the code where the error shows:

```
DataSet dsDelP = new DataSet();
string sql = "";
sql = "SELECT Grupi_ID, (p.emri + ' ' + p.mbiemri) as Profesori , k.EmriKlases as Klasa, d.emri as Dita, Ora_fillimit as Fillimi, Ora_mbarimit as Mbarimi";
sql += "FROM grupetOraret gro";
sql += "inner join Profesori p on gro.Profesori_ID=p.Profesor_ID";
sql += "inner join Klasa k on gro.Klasa_ID=k.Klasa_ID";
sql += "inner join Dita d on gro.ID_Dita=d.ID_dita";

SqlDataAdapter daDelP = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
daDelP.Fill(dsDelP, "grupetOraret");
dataGridViewKerkoOrarin.DataSource = dsDelP.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: syntax errorr near "grupetOraret"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no spaces. You should add them in every line (in its beggining or ending). This is how it should look like, assuming the query itself is correct (as soon as you checked it already):

```
sql = "SELECT Grupi_ID, (p.emri + ' ' + p.mbiemri) as Profesori , k.EmriKlases as Klasa,  d.emri as Dita, Ora_fillimit as Fillimi, Ora_mbarimit as Mbarimi ";
sql += "FROM grupetOraret gro ";
sql += "inner join Profesori p on gro.Profesori_ID=p.Profesor_ID ";
sql += "inner join Klasa k on gro.Klasa_ID=k.Klasa_ID ";
sql += "inner join Dita d on gro.ID_Dita=d.ID_dita ";
```

Comment: @LoniiZenku you could see the problem yourself, if you watched the result value of `sql` in debug. You're welcome

Comment: i cant watch..because im not programing the application.my friend does. she called me and we were discussing it over the phone, she send me a part of the code where the error was. anyway thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL looks like this after the strings are concatenated:

```
SELECT ... as MbarimiFROM .... on gro.Profesori_ID=p.Profesor_IDinner ...
```

You need a space between the last word on each line and the first word on the next line:

```
string sql = "... as Mbarimi";
sql += " FROM ...";
sql += " inner join Profesori p on gro.Profesori_ID=p.Profesor_ID";
sql += " inner join Klasa k on gro.Klasa_ID=k.Klasa_ID";
sql += " inner join Dita d on gro.ID_Dita=d.ID_dita";
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending to the sql variable doesn't automatically insert newlines, so `sql` will end up looking like

```
...FROM grupetOraret groinner join Profesori p on gro.Profesori_ID=p.Profesor_ID...
```

Note that `grupetOraret gro` and `inner join` have no space between them.

Try using `@` for multi-line string literals, makes things easier and more efficient:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT Grupi_ID, (p.emri + ' ' + p.mbiemri) as Profesori , k.EmriKlases as Klasa, d.emri as Dita, Ora_fillimit as Fillimi, Ora_mbarimit as Mbarimi
    FROM grupetOraret gro
    inner join Profesori p on gro.Profesori_ID=p.Profesor_ID
    inner join Klasa k on gro.Klasa_ID=k.Klasa_ID
    inner join Dita d on gro.ID_Dita=d.ID_dita";
```